# how many number can be formed(condition)

Tags: probability, permutations

How many $3$ digit number $x > 350$ can be formed by using digit $0 ,1,2,3,4,5,6$
 if each digit can be used only once?

So my understanding is there would be three cases here.

First one is first digit start with $3$ but and second digit is $5$ and third digit is $1,2,3$ and so on.
that would be $$1 \times  1 \times 6$$

Second case is start with $3$ , second is $6$
that would be $$1\times  1 \times 7$$

Third case is number start with $4,5,6$ and the rest follows
that would be $$3\times 6 \times 5$$

is my way of doing it true?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: oh , forgot to write my answer.

Comment: What was the answer?

Comment: the scheme said 99

Answer (score 1):

If the first digit is $3$, the second digit is $6$ and no restriction for the last digit. $$1 \times 1 \times 5$$

Notice that even as that the number of possible number for the last digit is only $5$ as $2$ digits have been used up previously.

If the first digits is $3$ and the second digit is $5$, we have to make sure the last digit is not $0$.

$$1 \times 1 \times 4$$

If the first digit is $4$ or $5$ or $6$, no restrictions on the last two digits.

$$3 \times 6 \times 5$$

Hence there should be $99$ ways.

Comment: oops, yeah. i'll correct it.thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1):

Using the cases you described above.

Case 1: $1*1*4 = 4$

Case 2: $1*1*5 = 5$

Case 3: $3*6*5 =90$

Total amount = $4+5+90 =99$

You had it set up right, but remember that no number can be repeated

Comment: Thanks to whoever edited my post. I believe the question was written down wrong and had >= before, which explains why I had an answer of 100